# Can't find installed packages in Lubuntu

Tags: package-management, lubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu on my laptop and installed Pjsip on my lubuntu .

For compiling purposes I need to locate the PJSIP library but I don't seem to be able to locate them or other system files for that matter.

In my file manager only Desktop and Documents appear and some other folders which don't contain any of the installed files.

In Ubuntu it was easy there was an **computer** icon where I could browse through all the files i had installed.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to install PJSIP?

Comment: no i need to navigate to the directory where the package has been installed and find the .pc file and include its path in a compilation process.The name of .pc files is most of the time different from the original package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my file manager only Desktop and Documents appear and some other folders which don't contain any of the installed files.
>
> In Ubuntu it was easy there was an computer icon where I could browse through all the files i had installed.

Assuming the file manager is PCManFM, to go "above" the home folder in which PCManFM opens by default, click the circled "^". If you've opened PCManFM to your home folder, clicking "^" twice will show you the system files such as `/bin`, `/local`, `/usr` and so on. The ">" and "<" are also used for navigation.

[image: PCManFM]

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg -L Pjsip` command will show you where the installed files are.

Comment: so you are saying there is no way to browse through the installed packages from the file manager?

Comment: Once you see the installation path for the package, you can browse it by writing the path to the file manager.

Comment: it wasnt quite the answer but gave me a hint. well in Lubuntu there is no Icon to navigate to installed files but entering '/' at the navigation bar did the trick

Comment: When you write above command, you will see paths of installed files such as "/usr/lib/somepackagename/libabc.so" from that package. Copy the path and write instead of '/', e.g. write '/usr/lib/somepackagename/'.

Answer (score 0):

The pkgconfig files are always (or most of the time) found in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/` which is the case for the PJ project development libraries:

```
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libpjproject.pc
```

Remember, that only the `-dev` files include the `.pc` files. So, if you don't have `libpjproject-dev` installed, you will never find the `.pc` files.